# Check time interval using SQL condition

Tags: sql, logic, conditional-statements, intervals

I'm storing some intervals in the SQL, example:

```
id INT
from DATE
to DATE
```

How can I check, using only one condition (if possible) if a NEW interval conflict with a existing one?

Examples:

```
|-----------| (from 1 to 5)
    |-----------| (from 2 to 6)
       |--| (from 3 to 4)
                   |--| (from 7 to 8)
```

Every interval (in the first three) has some conflict with the other two intervals... Except  the last one that's alone.

--

This check can be achieved using some condition like:

```
WHERE (`from` <= $FROM and `to` >= $TO)
```

But this only check intervals that **contains** the new one... Not the other intervals that has some **intersections** OR the ones that's **inside** the new one.

Maybe something like this?

```
WHERE NOT (`from` < $FROM and `to` < $TO) AND NOT (`from` > $FROM and `to` > $TO)
```

Obs.: I need to find the collisions to alert the user that this new period already exist or get in conflict with an existin one.

Comment: What representation of periods are you using e.g. closed-open? Put another way, would you consider `(from 1 to 5)` to collide with `(from 5 to 6)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE ($TO >= `from` AND $FROM <= `to`)
```

Note this works for the case where the new range overlaps the whole range, when it only partially overlaps and when it encompasses it as well.

Comment: I used to work in GIS systems back in the 80s.  Intersections and overlaps are second nature to me.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question and just wanted to try to show how a truth table can identify the reduced logic that Paul already posted.

Assume you have an interval `from [ to ]` that you want to check against `from { to }`.

This translates to the following truth table:

```
 #   [ < {   [ < }   ] < {   ] < }    Collision?  Example
 1     T       T       T       T          F       [ ] { }
 2     T       T       T       F          T       [ } { ] *
 3     T       T       F       T          T       [ { ] }
 4     T       T       F       F          T       [ { } ]
 5     T       F       T       T          T       ] } [ { *
 6     T       F       T       F          T       } [ ] { *
 7     T       F       F       T          Contradiction
 8     T       F       F       F          T       } [ { ] *
 9     F       T       T       T          T       ] { [ } *
10     F       T       T       F          Contradiction
11     F       T       F       T          T       { [ ] }
12     F       T       F       F          T       { [ } ]
13     F       F       T       T          T       ] { } [ *
14     F       F       T       F          T       } ] { [ *
15     F       F       F       T          T       { ] } [ *
16     F       F       F       F          F       { } [ ]
```

Looking at this truth table, the simplest expression to identify collisions is:

`NOT ( [ < { AND [ < } AND ] < { AND ] < } ) AND NOT ( [ >= { AND [ >= } AND ] >= { AND ] >= } )`

However we know that, since `{ < }` and `[ < ]`, this reduces to

`NOT ( [ < { AND ] < { ) AND NOT ( [ >= } AND ] >= } )`

Which corresponds to the SQL:

`WHERE NOT ('from' < $FROM and 'to' < $FROM ) AND NOT ('from' > $TO and 'to' > $TO)` (similar to what @TiuTalk suggested).

However, we have already assumed that `{ < }` and `[ < ]`.  This is critical.  Look at the rows marked `*` in the truth table.  In those rows, either `} < {` or `] < [`.  We know those won't happen.  Plus, some rows imply completely contradictory things like `} < { AND { < }` which we know to be impossible.  Eliminating all these rows gives just 6 rows:

```
 #   [ < {   [ < }   ] < {   ] < }    Collision?  Example
 1     T       T       T       T          F       [ ] { }
 3     T       T       F       T          T       [ { ] }
 4     T       T       F       F          T       [ { } ]
11     F       T       F       T          T       { [ ] }
12     F       T       F       F          T       { [ } ]
16     F       F       F       F          F       { } [ ]
```

Here, we can see that just the middle two clauses determine whether there's a collision.  Namely, `( [ < } ) AND NOT ( ] < { )`.  This is equivalent to `( [ < } ) AND ( ] >= { )` (negating the second comparator) which is equivalent to the SQL `WHERE ('from' < $TO AND 'to' >= $FROM)`.  This is semantically equivalent to Paul's clause (barring working through the `<=` to the end).